# Is there any risk installing MinGW64 on Windows 10?

Tags: mingw64

I'd like to confirm that there is no risk because this is a borrowed computer, with which I would rather not even take a small chance.

Comment: Said yourself that it should not be any problem, and it shouldn't. MinGW64 and Cygwin could always be uninstalled. Do you have a specific concern? You can always check the source pages and release notes for known issues, and if any of those are of particular concern to you, don't install it.

Comment: thank you I will check it

Comment: Please do you know where is the real source page, I fount a lot of download pages

Comment: The official website is [this](http://mingw.org/)

Comment: I was really afraid of killing mi friend's PC. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There shouldn't be a risk, though installing anything (or even just turning the computer on) does involve some chance that a problem could develop.

I don't know if this helps, but I house sat for a friendly acquaintance for a week, during which some problem developed with his (land line) phone.  It had to do with the wiring and was clearly an issue that was long in developing, but on his return, he asked for money anyway.  I figured he he was boorish enough to do that, I could be boorish enough to say, "No."

So, what happens if the hard drive dies?  One of the DIMMS fail?  It's hard to quantify these risks.

Comment: Thank you, I will install the compiler and if anything goes wrong, I will uninstall it

Comment: Ok.  You could accept that answer, if that works for you.  (Green check mark.)

Comment: Ok bro thank you  again